# Issue with the __name__=="__main__" function calling

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm struggling with a python program to redirect the output of all print calls to a file and email it. Below is my program. Everything works fine except the `OUTFILE` in the email coming up empty (perhaps the file is still open while it tries to email it). As I'm little confused about the sequence and want to call the `send_status_report()` defined after the file is closed, how do I make it work.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import os
import pty
import sys
import smtplib
import time
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication


def current_time():
    from datetime import datetime
    return datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')


BIN="/home/netsys/filerscripts/MANU-TEST/storage-automations/REDBUTTON-DR/"
LOG=BIN+"Logs/"
YMD=current_time()
OUTFILE="ResyncLog_"+YMD+".txt"
SMTP_SERVER="xxxxxxxx.xxx.com"

#define to Call the reverse resync and output the log to both file and screen


def send_status_report():
    dir_path = LOG
    files = [OUTFILE, "CLUSTERDEL.LOG", "RESYNC.LOG","UPDATE.LOG"]

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['To'] = "abc@abc.com"
    msg['From'] = "abc@abc.com"
    msg['Subject'] = "Netapp RB Automation:Reverse Resync Status"

    body = MIMEText('Test results attached.', 'html', 'utf-8')  
    msg.attach(body)  # add message body (text or html)

    for f in files:  # add files to the message
        file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, f)
        attachment = MIMEApplication(open(file_path, "rb").read(), _subtype="txt")
        attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment', filename=f)
        msg.attach(attachment)

    s = smtplib.SMTP()
    s.connect(host=SMTP_SERVER)
    s.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
    print 'done!'
    s.close()


def main():
    subprocess.call(BIN+"ReverseSync.py", shell=True)



if __name__=="__main__":
    sentinel_option = '--dont-spawn'
    if sentinel_option not in sys.argv:
        # run itself copying output to the log file
        with open(LOG+OUTFILE, 'wb') as log_file:
            def read(fd):
                data = os.read(fd, 1024)
                log_file.write(data)
                #OUTDATA = OUTDATA + data
                return data

            argv = [sys.executable] + sys.argv + [sentinel_option]
            rc = pty.spawn(argv, read)

    else:
        sys.argv.remove(sentinel_option)
        rc = main()
    sys.exit(rc)

send_status_report()
```

Comment: You have a `with open…:`. So the next line after that `with` block finishes (that is, after the `rc = pty.spawn(argv, read)`), the file is closed. So if you want to call `send_status_report(0` after the file is closed, just add a line there that does `send_status_report()`.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then your code is _already_ broken, because it's somehow closing the file before you're done with it, so where you add more code isn't really important.

Comment: But meanwhile, why are you doing all of this? Why do you need to have the script run another instance of itself at all? Why do you need to capture its stdout instead of just making it write to a file in the first place? Even if you need that, why do you need to use `pty` to fool it into believing its stdout is the tty?

Comment: Im not the owner of the first script and I dont have the liberty to edit it. Also, its a huge script and I dont want to break it by making changes..make sense?

Comment: However, the code is not broken and it worked after I placed the send_status_report() as you mentioned.. Appreciate your help !

Comment: But you _are_ editing the script. But… whatever, if it works for you, fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As Im little confused about the sequence and want to call the send_status_report() define after the file is closed, how do I make it work.

You have a `with open…:`. That statement will automatically close the file when the block is finished. So, if you want to run something right after the file is closed, just put it right after that statement:

```
with open(LOG+OUTFILE, 'wb') as log_file:
    def read(fd):
    # ...
    rc = pty.spawn(argv, read)

send_status_report()
```

As long as your existing code is working (e.g., the file isn't getting closed before you're done with it), and isn't doing anything really weird like closing the file multiple times, this will call `send_status_report()` right after the file is closed.